# animating a div to the center with velocity.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, velocity.js

I have a list of divs and I want to use velocity to animate the first item of it. The action is supposed to be that the div becomes a circle and has a different color and also remains centered.

The code for the HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="paper"><h3>Box 1</h3></div>
    <div class="paper"><h3>Hello Word</h3></div>
    <div class="paper"><h3>2 + 2 = 5</h3></div>
    <div class="paper"><h3>Final box</h3></div>
</div>
```

For the CSS

```
body{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#container{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.paper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.paper:hover{
    background-color: #607D8B;
    color: white;
}
```

and the js code:

```
 window.onload = function(){
            var $box1 = $('.paper').eq(0);
            $box1.on("click",function(){
                $box1.velocity({borderRadius: '50%',
                                width:'100px',
                                backgroundColor:'#4CAF50',
                                color:'#fff',
                                marginLeft:'auto',
                                marginRight:'auto'
                                },
                               {duration:500,easing:'easeInQuad'});
            });

        }
```

Basically everything works except that the clicked div is always animating to the left part of the container. I thought that setting MarginLeft and MarginRight to auto would prevent that, but apparently not (however, setting MarginLeft to 40% works). How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox to keep things centered.

In your example I just added this properties to your container

```
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
```

Check this working fiddle

```js
var $box1 = $('.paper').eq(0);
            $box1.on("click",function(){
                $box1.velocity({borderRadius: '50%',
                                width:'100px',
                                backgroundColor:'#4CAF50',
                                color:'#fff'
                                },
                               {duration:500,easing:'easeInQuad'});
            });
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#container{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  
}
.paper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.paper:hover{
    background-color: #607D8B;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="paper"><h3>Box 1</h3></div>
    <div class="paper"><h3>Hello Word</h3></div>
    <div class="paper"><h3>2 + 2 = 5</h3></div>
    <div class="paper"><h3>Final box</h3></div>
</div>
```